# Can't understand SNORT rule pcre option syntax "?P=name"

Tags: snort, programming

While trying to understand some SNORT rule lines, I came across the following syntax that I could not figure. Could not find any description in the manual (though admittedly I've not read it all throughly yet).

Two examples with the parts in question highlighted.

```
From sid:17166  
pcre:"/(?P<var>\w+)\x2Ereplace\x28\s*(?P=var)\s*\x2C\s*(?P=var)\s*\x29/";
:      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^

From sid:29503  
pcre:"/removeChild\((?<element>\w{1,20})\).*(?P=element)\.getCharNumAtPosition/smi";
:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It looks like the "? " part is connected with the latter use of the name as "?P=name". But, it is not consistent (as seen in the two cases above).

<sup>References.</sup>
<sup>sid:17166; reference:bugtraq,36343; reference:cve,2009-3075;</sup>
<sup>sid:29503; reference:bugtraq,49213; reference:cve,2011-0084; reference:url,osvdb.org/show/osvdb/74581;</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(?P<var>\w+)`

How to read this expression:

```
'('        = Open matching group.
'?P<var>'  = call this matching group "var"
'\w+'      = one or more alphanumeric/underscore characters
')'        = close matching group.
```

Next part is simply asking for the named backreference:

```
(?P=var)
```

For the next piece of syntax:

```
(?<element>\w{1,20})

'('          = open matching group.
'?<element>' = Name this matching group "element"
'\w{1,20}'   = match any alphanumeric or underscore a minimum of once, and a maximum of 20 times.
')'          = close matching group
```

Comment: Thanks for the expansion. I am still trying to understand the difference between the two syntax examples. Particularly, the missing 'P' in the second case for back-reference. I'd love to see a `SNORT` reference describing it like the regex reference @Anorov gave does.

Comment: @Anorov's link provides the history.  Python gave us the syntax `(?P<name>group)` first, and then later C# gave us `(?<name>group)`.  Perl adopted both syntaxes in version 5.10.  Generally, as far as "standards" go, if a product is "PCRE" compliant, it usually means it works in Perl 5.10.  (Which isn't really a standard...)

Comment: @nik It's just an inconsistency in how different languages decided to design their regex syntax. They're equivalent; you just have to remember which languages support which, and which support both.

Comment: Thanks for your updates @Anorov and `avgvstvs`. The language of interest to me at this time is the one SNORT accepts. And I see rules using both forms. Will assimilate these details further. For I accept this answer.

Comment: Did a little bit of digging.  http://seclists.org/focus-ids/2006/Jan/95 <--Says that snort uses the PCRE lib --> http://www.pcre.org/

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Snort follows the general PCRE standard. You can read more details here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: Thanks for throwing the reference at me `:-)`. I have no good reason for having missed to look up there.